# For each <item> in CheckedListBox. <item> returns as Object and not as Control

Tags: vb.net, object, foreach, controls, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox previously populated. I want to loop with a "for each / next" through all items in the CheckedListBox and do a lot of "stuff" with each iteration element of the checkedlistbox.

example code:

```
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.Items

        If item.Checked = True Then

            'do stuff like
            item.BackColor = Color.Blue

        Else

            'do other stuff
            item.BackColor = Color.Brown

        End If

    Next
```

the problem is that  is an 'Object' type and not a 'Control' type. If I force the iteration var As CheckBox, it throws an InvalidCastException saying that type 'System.String' can't be associated with type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

I know I can easily work around this but I want to use a for each /next loop since I have a lot of code in that loop (and With can't be used) and always poiting directly to the object is something I wish to avoid and I really need the code to be as simple as possible.

I actually spent one afternoon looking for this but couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `CheckedListBox` is not a collection of `CheckBox` controls.
It does not have a collection of wrapper objects.

The CheckedListBox control is a simple control that can only display a plain list of items; it sounds like you're looking for something more powerful.  (For example, it is impossible to change the background color of an individual item without owner-drawing)

You should use a `ListView` (with the `CheckBoxes` property set to true) instead.
You can then loop through the `ListViewItem` instances in its `Items` collection.

Comment: Yes, but CheckedListBox isn't powerful enough for you.

Comment: Not much to figure out, actually. The object you are getting is the actual object you added to the list (in your case, a string I believe). Not the "list item" created for it. Visually customizing the individual items would require coding an owner-drawn listbox, which would be another lesson altogether.

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each item In SuppliersCheckList.CheckedItems
        If SuppliersCheckList.GetItemCheckState(SuppliersCheckList.Items.IndexOf(item)) Then
            MsgBox(item.ToString)
        End If
Next
```

Comment: This works nicely.  But it doesn't seem that the If statement is necessary.  Simply using CheckedItems filters out unchecked items for you.