# How do I color CheckedListBox items in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, checkedlistbox

I am making a personal application in VB.NET that uses a CheckedListBox to store items.  I have three buttons on my form, with which I would like to change the selected item's color with (to green, orange, and red.)

I have tried numerous approaches to this issue and have had no such luck.  Could someone lend a helping hand?

Comment: CheckedListBox was implemented from ListBox by using custom painting.  You cannot easily customize it again without completely re-implementing it.  Using ListView is good advice.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ListView instead. It has support for checkboxes and selected item colors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar answer here:

[For each <item> in CheckedListBox. <item> returns as Object and not as Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505119/for-each-item-in-checkedlistbox-item-returns-as-object-and-not-as-control)

Basically, this control won't do what you want it to (at least not without much complexity).  You need to upgrade your control to a ListView.

Comment: I would really rather use a CheckedListBox.. :\

Answer (score 1):

You can also use TreeView that looks and acts like a checked list box:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Me.TreeView1.ShowLines = False

Me.TreeView1.CheckBoxes = True

Dim MyColors() As Color = {Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Aqua}

For x As Integer = 0 To 4

Dim NewNode As TreeNode = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Node" & x)

NewNode.ForeColor = MyColors(x)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I would really rather use a CheckedListBox

Answer (score 1):

Took the advice of using a ListView.  Looked and worked great on my Windows 7 and Vista boxes but on XP, the ListView did not display properly (items were crunched overtop of one another, checkboxes didn't always display).  Checked to make sure it was not a framework version issue and that it was not a screen resolution issue.  Ended up retreating back to the CheckedListBox implementation which did NOT have the inconsistency.

**Found this solution that accomplished the removal of the blue highlight in the CheckedListBox scenario for me.  Using it however you have to keep track of the selection in another manner (global variable, looking at the checked item(s), etc.).**

I simply clear the selected item(s) after processing the "..._SelectedIndexChanged".  The first thing I do in the "..._SelectedIndexChange" is test for no Selection and do nothing if that is the change.  The result is that the currently selected item appears unselected (and actually is unselected, i.e. no blue highlight) however the CheckBox remains checked indicating the most recent selection for the user.

**Example ==>**

```
Private Sub ModelCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,...
    Dim x As Short = ModelCheckedListBox.SelectedIndex
    If x >= 0 Then

  'Something I always do since the Selection Mode = "One" doesn't bother to clear
        'the checks itself

        ModelCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(x, True)
        If ModelCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Count > 1 Then
            For Each item In ModelCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices
                If item <> x Then
                    ModelCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(item, False)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        ModelCheckedListBox.Refresh()

  'More of your code

        ModelCheckedListBox.ClearSelected()
    End If
End Sub
```