# How to change CheckedListBox Item Color

Tags: c#, .net, colors, checkedlistbox

I thought it would be as simple as

```
CheckedListBox1.Item[i].BackColor = ....
```

But I can't find anything on the **intellisense** or google searches.

I want to set a specific color for each item in the Checked List Box

Comment: [A CheckedListBox is not a collection of CheckBox controls.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505145/284240)

Comment: so using a ListView (with the CheckBoxes property set to true) is the only way to achieve this functionality?